# Reference single symbols in equation?

Tags: math-mode, cross-referencing, counters

Is there a way to use the `equation` counter for referencing single symbols inside the equation instead of the whole equation? For example like this

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

$$\Phi(x)\underset{(1)}{=}\lambda x~,$$
Reference (1) later in the text.

\end{document}
```

Whole equations and symbol references should use the same counter, so they cannot interfere with one another and the symbol reference should work in `$$...$$` as well as `align*` environment.

My first attempt implementing this looks like this

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\oplabel}[1]{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation\label{#1})}

\begin{document}

$$\Phi(x)\underset{\oplabel{somename}}{=}\lambda x~,$$
Reference \eqref{somename} later in the text.

\end{document}
```

and it works for `$$...$$`, but neither for `\begin{align}...\nonumber\end{align}` nor for `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}`.

Is there a way to use the `equation` counter in the `align*` environment too? (I know the `*` stands for "no line counting", but I'd like to manually add references where I need them without numbering every line.)

Comment: Side note: `$$...$$` is deprecated. Use `\[...\]`.  And `align*` does not use the equation counter. Another issue is that the `align` etc. redefine `\label`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why `\label` does not work the expected way is that that `amsmath` package redefines it.

In order to provide a working version, use the original version of `\label` which is stored by `amsmath` into `\ltx@label`. This will work for `align`, `align*` and `\[...\]` as well.

Side note: Don't use `$$...$$`, that's deprecated syntax, use `\[...\]` instead.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\oplabel}[1]{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation\ltx@label{#1})}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\[\Phi(x)\underset{\oplabel{somename}}{=}\lambda x,\]

\begin{align}
  \Phi(x)&\underset{\oplabel{someothername}}{=}\lambda x~ \nonumber
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
  \Phi(x)&\underset{\oplabel{yetanothername}}{=}\lambda x~ 
\end{align*}

Reference \eqref{someothername} or \eqref{somename} or \eqref{yetanothername} later in the text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On thinking about this: Perhaps, it's better to use a different counter and not `equation` for this.

Comment: Works great. Thank you :)
Still wondering, why it might be better to not use ```equation``` for this?

Comment: @Cubinator73: You're referencing a symbol rather than an equation. But its a matter of taste, in the end.

Comment: Oh ok. I like writing an equation into a single line and referencing single steps with text more than writing multiple lines of equations and little text inbetween. That's the reason behind this question.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer +1 I vote positive always to my friends.